# Can't install.sh Arduino software

Tags: command-line, 20.04, ide, arduino

Following the instructions on the Arduino install [page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux), once I arrive in my extracted directory and run `install.sh` in the terminal, I get the message:

`install.sh: command not found`

How do I install the Arduino software on Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to type `./install.sh` instead.

The `./` indicates that you want to run a file in your current working directiry.
Without the leading `./` linux will search in your $PATH for an executable program with that name.

Comment: I don't fully understand this. 'install.sh' is inside my cwd. What is ``./`` doing? I thought by typing xyz.xxx in my cwd it would indicate that I want to run that file.

Comment: The `./` indicates that you want to run a file in your current working directiry.

Comment: Note that `.` (dot) implied your current directory.

Comment: A bit of explanation: only files in your $PATH will be executed without the need of specifying their full path. By typing `./` before the executable name, you provide the full path. You could add `"."` to your $PATH, meaning "whatever the current directory is", in order to avoid having to type `./` before every executable in your current directory. However, this is not recommended, as it is a security exposure.